# Pandas DataFrame to MySQL Table: AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I tried to load a pandas dataframe into a table of a mysql database using a simple example but it throws the above error message.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

testdict = {
    'objects': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    'values': [34,12,9]
           }
df=pd.DataFrame(testdict)
    
connection = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://root:****@localhost/testdb')
df.to_sql(con=connection, name="testtable", if_exists="append", index=False)
```

Working with Python 3.8.10 and pandas v. 1.2.0
The connection to the database works fine with other operations.
Previous discussions on similar questions did not help. So, any suggestion would be appreciated!
Many thanks, Thomas

Full Error Message:

runcell(0, 'C:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/Data/untitled9.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\Data\untitled9.py", line 20, in 
df.to_sql(con=connection, name="testtable", if_exists="append", index=False)

File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2776, in to_sql
sql.to_sql(

File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 590, in to_sql
pandas_sql.to_sql(

File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1843, in to_sql
table.create()

File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 722, in create
if self.exists():

File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 709, in exists
return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)

File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1854, in has_table
return len(self.execute(query, [name]).fetchall()) > 0

File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1695, in execute
cur = self.con.cursor()

AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Comment: Add the full stack trace please.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: code works for my database MySQL, Python 3.8.10, pandas 1.3.3, LInux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Sorry for having missed this. I just added the full error message. Thanks balderman and furas.